# How to create a clickable datatable rows and when clicked move to different page based on the value in the row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have created a bootstrap datatable with just header names. The row values in the table are going to come dynamically when I fill a form. Now when I click on any row of the table it should redirect me to a different page based on the id value of the row. now in my case if ID = 3 and Name = Roger it should redirect me to a page which displays ID as 3 and Name as Roger.

```
       <table id="test">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Age
                </th>
                <th>
                    Game
                </th>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

I am a newbie in Jquery. Can anyone help me with the jquery code? I have created a query like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("tr").not(':first').click(function () {
    let name = $(this).find("td:first").text();
    let age = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
    let game = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text();
    let id = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text();
    let newUrl = "/Details/Index/view?id=" + id + "&name=" + name;
    location.href = newUrl;
 });
});
```

Here Details is my Controller name and Index is my view name. It is not redirecting to the page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you please add the code you already have? this would help us answer your question faster and also would give you more answers.

Comment: @Dennis van de Hoef I have edited my code

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").not(':first').click(function(){
       let id = $(this).find("td:first").text();
       let name = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
       let newUrl = "http://example.com/view?id=" + id + "&name="  + name;
       location.href= newUrl;
    });
 });
```

Comment: How to make that rows clickable? And in my tables I don't have tbody so can I still specify it as $("tbody tr")?

Comment: Can you please specify what is that td:first and td:eq(1)?

Comment: @neethu The rows are clickable when you assign an eventhandler click() to them. In my example I considered you would use tbody as you are also using thead, but I can adjust my answer to the absence of tbody.

Comment: @neethu td:first is the cell that contains the value of id and td:eq(1) is the second cell which contains the name, based on your header these are the cells where this information is available.

Comment: Yeah I am not using tbody.

Comment: @neethu I've adjusted my answer so there is no tbody anymore.

Comment: @neethu I've created this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9ntkq4xe/2/ where the url is on click output in the console so you can see it's working.

Comment: @ matthias_h Is it redirecting or something? For me, it is not showing like clickable.

Comment: @neethu I've adjusted the cursor here: https://jsfiddle.net/9ntkq4xe/3/ so it shows that it's clickable.

Comment: I have edited my code. But still, it is not redirecting.

Comment: @neethu I think you need the complete URL for this to work and not a relative one like you have (http://example.com/details/index/view etc instead of /details/index/view).

Comment: @neethu I've adjusted the fiddle to go to the URL so you can see that it is working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/w6hb1c4x/

Answer (score 0):

use onclick attribute on `<td>`

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Game</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="document.location='www.url.com/01'" >
    <td>01</td>
    <td>Walter White</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="document.location='www.url.com/02'" >>   
    <td>02</td>
    <td>Jesse Pinkman</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Friday the 13th</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use js to dynamically add the custom URL for each row.